# Require type annotations for variables in Typescript

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I want to disable type inference for variables in Typescript but I cannot find any way to do it.

The reason I want to do this, is mainly because of migration to promises.

Sometimes I have code like this:

```
myFunction() : string {
  ....
  return "some string";
}
const x = myFunction();
if(x != undefined){
  do_something_important;
}
```

and it works fine, x gets to be of type string and type checking works and everything goes well.

But if for some reason, I need to change myFunction to return a Promise instead of the direct value, then I change it but:

```
myFunction() : Promise<string> { //or async myFunction()...
  ....
  return some_promise;
}
const x = myFunction();  //Now x is a Promise!!, no warning!
if(x != undefined){      //x will never be undefined!!
  do_something_important;
}
```

Since the type of x is inferred, no errors or warnings are thrown, and **now x will never be undefined** and my code will do unexpected things. So, I need to remember to change everywhere I have used myFunction and declare variables like this:

```
const x : string = myFunction()
```

Then it does validate and shows a warning saying that a promise cannot be assigned to a string!! so then I have change it to something like this:

```
const x : string = await myFunction()
```

**And that's GREAT!** Now it'll work as expected, but since typescript does not forces me to declare the type of the variable explicitly, I keep forgetting to do so, and often I have to work with promises and the same scenario repeats.
I think it would be ok to not have to declare type when using constant values , like numbers or strings i.e. `let x = 0;`, but with functions it can get really tricky specially if they return promises or types that can be compatible between them.

**Is there a way to disable type inference and force me to declare variable type?**

I guess I could set the flat `noImplicitAny` flag and do not initialize the variables at the time of declaration,  but that would prevent me from using `const` apart from making for uglier code, and also, very easy to forget so not really a solution.

Comment: why not to use like   `x : any = await myFunction()`

Comment: if I have previous code that does not uses promises and then change it to promises, then this has the same problem so no...

Comment: Would a linting rule be of some assistance? https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/

Comment: Not really sure, if it does what I want then maybe. I would like a pure typescript solution if possible

Comment: I created this fiddler to show another case where this would be useful: https://jsfiddle.net/lando_orellana/1b68eLdr/80716/, in that case the function changes from returning a string to return an array, and no warning because of type inference

Comment: The `typedef` tslint rule is probably the best solution.  It's worth nothing, there's another lint rule, [`strict-type-predicates`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/strict-type-predicates/), that will detect comparisons to `null` or `undefined` that are always true or always false.  This won't help with the second example though.

Answer (score -1):

Typescript is more powerful and it provide additional types assigned using '|' keyword.

```
myFunction() : Promise<string> { //or async myFunction()...
  ....
  return "some string";
}
const x = myFunction();  //Now x is a Promise!!, no warning!
if(x != undefined){      //x will never be undefined!!
  do something;
}


const x: any = await myFunction();

export type defaultType = Promise<String> | String | Number | ...;
const x: defaultType = await myFunction();
```

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear, I WILL be returning promises now instead of base types, so this will not work either. I updated my question to clarify this

Comment: Typescript won't allow to disable type inference. Typescript created for strong typing as one of the reason. may be you can try any or export type. Updated answer above

Comment: Actually what I'm asking is for stronger typing, type inference in this cases makes for weak typing